# How to plot lagged data against other data in R

Tags: r, dataframe, lag

I would like to lag one variable by, say, 10 time steps and plot it against the other variable which remains the same. I would like to do this for various lags to see if there is a time period that the first variable influences the other. The data I have is daily and after lagging I am separating into Dec-Feb data only. The problem I am having is the plot and correlation between the lagged variable and the other data is coming out the same as the non-lagged plot and correlation every time. I am not sure how to achieve this.

A sample of my data frame "data" can be seen below.

```
         Date           x             y
14158 2017-10-05  1.913918e+00 -0.1538234614
14159 2017-10-06  1.479714e+00 -0.1937094170
14160 2017-10-07  8.783669e-01 -0.1703790211
14161 2017-10-08  5.706581e-01 -0.1294144428
14162 2017-10-09  4.979405e-01 -0.0666569815
14163 2017-10-10  3.233477e-01  0.0072006102
14164 2017-10-11  3.057630e-01  0.0863445067
14165 2017-10-12  5.877673e-01  0.1097707831
14166 2017-10-13  1.208526e+00  0.1301967193
14167 2017-10-14  1.671705e+00  0.1728109268
14168 2017-10-15  1.810979e+00  0.2264911145
14169 2017-10-16  1.426651e+00  0.2702958315
14170 2017-10-17  1.241140e+00  0.3242637704
14171 2017-10-18  8.997498e-01  0.3879727861
14172 2017-10-19  5.594161e-01  0.4172990825
14173 2017-10-20  3.980254e-01  0.3915170864
14174 2017-10-21  2.138538e-01  0.3249736995
14175 2017-10-22  3.926440e-01  0.2224834840
14176 2017-10-23  2.268644e-01  0.0529143372
14177 2017-10-24  5.664923e-01 -0.0081443464
14178 2017-10-25  6.167520e-01  0.0312073984
14179 2017-10-26  7.751882e-02  0.0043897693
14180 2017-10-27 -5.634851e-02 -0.0726825266
14181 2017-10-28 -2.122061e-01 -0.1711305549
14182 2017-10-29 -8.500991e-01 -0.2068581639
14183 2017-10-30 -1.039685e+00 -0.2909120824
14184 2017-10-31 -3.057745e-01 -0.3933633317
14185 2017-11-01 -1.288774e-01 -0.3726346136
14186 2017-11-02 -5.608007e-03 -0.2425754386
14187 2017-11-03  4.853990e-01 -0.0503543980
14188 2017-11-04  5.822672e-01  0.0896130098
14189 2017-11-05  8.491505e-01  0.1299151006
14190 2017-11-06  1.052999e+00  0.0749888307
14191 2017-11-07  1.170470e+00  0.0287317882
14192 2017-11-08  7.919862e-01  0.0788187381
14193 2017-11-09  4.574565e-01  0.1539981316
14194 2017-11-10  4.552032e-01  0.2034393145
14195 2017-11-11 -3.621350e-01  0.2077476707
14196 2017-11-12 -8.053965e-01  0.1759558604
14197 2017-11-13 -8.307459e-01  0.1802858410
14198 2017-11-14 -9.421325e-01  0.2175529008
14199 2017-11-15 -9.880204e-01  0.2392924580
14200 2017-11-16 -7.448127e-01  0.2519253751
14201 2017-11-17 -8.081435e-01  0.2614254732
14202 2017-11-18 -1.216806e+00  0.2629971336
14203 2017-11-19 -1.122674e+00  0.3469995055
14204 2017-11-20 -1.242597e+00  0.4553094014
14205 2017-11-21 -1.294885e+00  0.5049438231
14206 2017-11-22 -9.325514e-01  0.4684133163
14207 2017-11-23 -4.632281e-01  0.4071673624
14208 2017-11-24 -9.689322e-02  0.3710270269
14209 2017-11-25  4.704467e-01  0.4126721465
14210 2017-11-26  8.682453e-01  0.3745057653
14211 2017-11-27  5.105564e-01  0.2373454931
14212 2017-11-28  4.747265e-01  0.1650783370
14213 2017-11-29  5.905379e-01  0.2632154120
14214 2017-11-30  4.083787e-01  0.3888834762
14215 2017-12-01  3.451736e-01  0.5008047592
14216 2017-12-02  5.161312e-01  0.5388177242
14217 2017-12-03  7.109279e-01  0.5515360710
14218 2017-12-04  4.458635e-01  0.5127537202
14219 2017-12-05 -3.986610e-01  0.3896493238
14220 2017-12-06 -5.968253e-01  0.1095843268
14221 2017-12-07 -1.604398e-01 -0.2455506506
14222 2017-12-08 -4.384744e-01 -0.5801038215
14223 2017-12-09 -7.255016e-01 -0.8384627087
14224 2017-12-10 -9.691828e-01 -0.9223171538
14225 2017-12-11 -1.140588e+00 -0.8177806761
14226 2017-12-12 -1.956622e-01 -0.5250998474
14227 2017-12-13 -1.083792e-01 -0.3430768534
14228 2017-12-14 -8.016345e-02 -0.3163476104
14229 2017-12-15  8.899266e-01 -0.2813253830
14230 2017-12-16  1.322833e+00 -0.2545953062
14231 2017-12-17  1.547972e+00 -0.2275373110
14232 2017-12-18  2.164907e+00 -0.3217205817
14233 2017-12-19  2.276258e+00 -0.5773412429
14234 2017-12-20  1.862291e+00 -0.7728091393
14235 2017-12-21  1.125083e+00 -0.9099696881
14236 2017-12-22  7.737118e-01 -1.2441963604
14237 2017-12-23  7.863508e-01 -1.4802661587
14238 2017-12-24  4.313111e-01 -1.4111320559
14239 2017-12-25 -8.814799e-02 -1.0024805520
14240 2017-12-26 -3.615127e-01 -0.4943077147
14241 2017-12-27 -5.011363e-01 -0.0308588186
14242 2017-12-28 -8.474088e-01  0.3717555895
14243 2017-12-29 -7.283247e-01  0.8230450219
14244 2017-12-30 -4.566981e-01  1.2495961116
14245 2017-12-31 -4.577034e-01  1.4805369230
14246 2018-01-01  1.946166e-01  1.5310004017
14247 2018-01-02  5.203149e-01  1.5384595802
14248 2018-01-03  5.024570e-02  1.4036679018
14249 2018-01-04 -7.065297e-01  1.0749574137
14250 2018-01-05 -8.741815e-01  0.7608524752
14251 2018-01-06  1.589530e-01  0.7891084646
14252 2018-01-07  8.632378e-01  1.1230358751
```

I am using

```
lagged <- lag(ts(x), k=10)
```

This is so the tsp isn't ignored. However, when I do

```
cor(data$x, data$y)
```

and

```
cor(lagged, data$y)
```

the result is the same, where I would have thought it would have been different. How do I get this lag to work before I can go ahead separate via date?

Many thanks!

Comment: `cor` will just calculate the correlation of those two variables - it does not take account of the dates, so the fact that you have shifted the dates of `lagged` won't affect it.  You need to remove the first 10 elements of `x` and the last 10 of `y` and then calculate the correlation of what is left. The function `ccf` might be what you are looking for, instead of `cor`.

Comment: try the `dplyr::lag`